# Ruby (CSV) 2.5.1 vs 2.3.3/2.4.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, mechanize

I am facing a rare issue with CSV parsing with ruby 2.5.1.
CSV file is a mechanize txt file. Parsing this file with ruby 2.3.3 or ruby 2.4.4 works perfectly. But I'm not able to parse the file with ruby 2.5.1. Do I need to update anything in order to parse in 2.5.1 ?

Bellow is my code.

```
csv_header = ["Rep Date", "Or No", "Qw Type", "Sett No", "Order Date", "AS Code", "ZCV", "Amount", "Qty", "BN Code", "AX Code", "User Id", "QW No", "QX Code", "WE No", "MN Code", "KL Name", "IO Id", "A AS", "DD Unit", "DD Amt", "DD Flag", "Remarks", "RRR", "KK Ref No", "TY Type", "SS Regn No", "SR Reg Date", "SU Code", "PPP", "QQQ DEC", "NM Flag", "DP Trans", "O Type"].freeze
response = agent.submit(form, button)

parsed = CSV.parse(response.body, col_sep: '|', write_headers: true, headers: csv_header)


# in ruby 2.3.3
parsed.count # 1523

# in ruby 2.5.1
parsed.count # 0

# data in response body looks like bellow
2018-12-05|234|T3|1819166|2018-12-03|489-AB|INFJF5|10000.0000|0|11887|RPBRANCH|1188701|20307754|489|PT2051|46A4CUM|AS Kapoor ||41.3500|241.8380|10000.0000|Y||0.0000|6662747|SP|3674288|24/10/2018|||N|Y|P|ASA|
2018-12-04|525|T3|1812366|2018-12-03|489-RR|INFJF5|1000.0000|0|11887|RPBRANCH|1188701|21551474|489|SW145481|VTI4JPA|Prasad P||41.3500|24.1840|1000.0000|Y||0.0000|78208832|STP|68798|24/09/2018|||N|Y|P|ASB|
```

I checked the version of CSV with `CSV::VERSION` which shows `"2.4.8"` in both console.

Comment: @engineersmnky let me try to understand. provided code works. But I don't have  header string attached at my csv file. Do I need to prepend the file with headers? If I don't mention the headers, parsed response will be a junk.

Comment: Haven't seen anywhere in the doc. Could you give some more context on this?

Comment: I see what you are saying. It appears that removing `write_headers` resolves this but it might be worth reporting. As it is clearly not functioning correctly